# How to receive Socket.IO socket using native socket module in Python

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, socket.io

When I am trying to receive a message from Socket.IO using the native socket module, instead of receiving the message, I receive this:

```
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MIlsTQ_ HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:5000

Connection: keep-alive

Accept: */*

Origin: http://localhost:8080

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36

DNT: 1

Referer: http://localhost:8080/

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

How do I fix this, and receive the message rather than the data?

Client code:

```
  socketsSend: function() {
  const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
  /*var socket = io.Socket('http://localhost', {
    port: 5000
  });*/
  socket.connect();
  socket._connectTimer = setTimeout(function() {
   socket.close();
  }, 500);

    socket.on('connect', function() {
// socket connected successfully, clear the timer
    clearTimeout(socket._connectTimer);
});
```

Server code:

```
import socket
import json
addr = 'localhost',5000
sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(addr)
sock.listen(3)
while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()
    data = connection.recv(100000)
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From  [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket) how to guide:

> In general, they *[socket's recv and send functions]* return when the associated network buffers have been filled (send) or
>    emptied (recv). They then tell you how many bytes they handled. It is your 
>    responsibility to call them again until your message has been completely dealt with.

So, from my understanding, `connection.recv(100000)` won't return any data until its buffer fills up, so to fix this you would need to set buffer to something low, (maybe 2048?).

Comment: The problem doesn't occur with normal sockets.